# Calculating future date using php strtotime() not give right answer

Tags: php

I want to get future date after specific date 
for this i use `strtotime()` function but it not work for me

then I use following code

```
$d1='2012-11-08';
$d2=date($d1, strtotime('+3 days'));    
echo $d2;
```

output is
     2012-11-08
     2012-11-08

not 
    2012-11-11

but output is not 2012-11-11
output is  2012-11-08
i can't solve this what is error i do and  how i solve this?

Comment: Have a look at what parameters [`date`](http://www.php.net/function.date) expects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `date_add`

```
$d1 = '2012-11-08';
$d2 = date_add($d1, date_interval_create_from_date_string('3 days'));
echo $d2;
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

If you're not running PHP 5.3, this should work:

```
$d1 = '2012-11-08';
$d2 = strtotime('+3 days', strtotime($d1));    
echo date('Y-m-d', $d2);
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function date_add() in F:\project\wamp\www\dat\s1.php on line 46

Comment: What version of php are you running? This code would require 5.3+

Comment: @master3w Wow, blast from the past. 4.3.0 was release December 2002. I'd recommend an update

Answer (score 3):

```
$d1='2012-11-08';
$d2=new DateTime($d1);
$d2->modify('+3 day');

echo $d2->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you wrongly added the `strtotime()`, it works when you use current date, if you want to add with customize date, You can try this,

```
<?php
 $d1='2012-11-08';
 $d2 = strtotime ( '+3 day' , strtotime ( $d1 ) ) ;
 $d3 = date ( 'Y-m-d' , $d2);
?>
```

if you want to add date from current date, use the following,

```
$d1 = Date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+3 days"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `date()` function incorrectly. As per the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), `date()` takes a format string followed by an optional timestamp. You're giving it a date string and another date.

You can do what you want like this, where `strtotime` is used to modify the date,

```
$date = "2012-11-08";
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date. " + 3 days"));
```

But if you're running PHP 5.2+ you should probably use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class, as it's got much better date handling, and it's easier to see what's going on with it.

```
$datetime = new DateTime("2012-11-08");
$datetime->modify("+ 3 days");    
echo $datetime->format("Y-m-d");
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst `strtotime()` is a handy tool, it is prone to locale issues.

I would instead use PHP's mature `DateTime` class, eg

```
$dt = new DateTime($d1);
echo $dt->add(new DateInterval('P3D'))->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::add() in F:\project\wamp\www\dat\s1.php on line 47

Comment: `DateTime::add()` was added in version 5.3.0. If you're stuck with 5.2, see [user1980114's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14743678/283366)

Comment: @master3w I doubt you're running PHP 4.3, otherwise you would have gotten a fatal error on the first line of my code